# Working with sub-folders in file path with sp_send_dbmail and T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

Is it possible to populate a sub-folder name in the `@file_attachements` path with some use of a wildcard?

I run a query to get the document name I'm looking for. I then assign that to a variable and concatenate the `@file_location` with `@document_name` to get the full path, but unfortunately I have an issue where that file name would be located in a sub-folder within the `@file_location`.

I have the following setup as an example:

```
DECLARE @file_attachment VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @file_location VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @my_email VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @BodyContent VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @EmailSubject VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DocumentName VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DocumentName = (SELECT Cast(Document_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as 'DocumentName'
                     FROM   dbo.tblDocuments
                     WHERE  TemplateID = 471
                            AND Cast(Document_Date AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() - 1 AS DATE))
SET @file_location ='\\server\directory\sub-directory\'
SET @my_email = 'computer.user@aol.com'
SET @file_attachment = @file_location + @DocumentName
```

The actual file would be located here `\\server\directory\sub-directory\another sub-dir\myfile.docx`

Since the second sub-directory will be different. I can't seem to account for that when I concatenate the `@file_location` and `@DocumentName`.

I can get it to send fine if I hard code the second sub-directory in the `@file_location`, but as I mentioned, that second folder will change.

The `@file_attachments` is then set to `= @file_location` when setting up `sp_send_dbmail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `xp_dirtree` for this since it will find files in sub-folders too if we set the `depth` to 0.

```
DECLARE @ParentFolder VARCHAR(256) = '\\server\directory\sub-directory\'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FileNames
CREATE TABLE #FileNames (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
    ,depth int
    ,isfile bit)
INSERT #FileNames (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC xp_dirtree @ParentFolder , 0, 1

SELECT * FROM #FileNames
```